# Get minimum water level of dam without loop

Tags: c++

I was given a problem. In the problem I am suppose to take input current month, current year and current water level of a dam from user. There is a scale that from month march to august the water level increase by 150 feet each month and from sep to feb it decreases by 200 feet. Now I am supposed to tell in which month and year the Dam will have no water or 0 feet water level. I have made the below program using loops but I have to it with out loops/recursive function. I got the year by dividing the water level with avg_decrease in water level.You cans see the program that does what I want with loop.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int c_month, c_year, wlevel, avg_decrease;
    cout<<"Enter current month number: ";
    cin>>c_month;
    cout<<"Enter current water level: ";
    cin>>wlevel;
    cout<<"Enter current year: ";
    cin>>c_year;
    avg_decrease = 300; //-25 each month, -300 each year
    cout<<wlevel/avg_decrease<<endl;

    int m = c_month, level = wlevel, y = c_year;
    while(true){
        if(x)
            break;
        for(int i =0;i<=12;i++){
            if(level < 0){
                x = true;
                break;
                }
            else if(m >= 3 && m<=8){
                level = level +150;
                m++;
                }
            else{
                level = level -200;
                if(m == 12)
                    m=1;
                else
                    m++;
            }
        }
        y++;
    }
    cout<<y<<"\t"<<m<<endl;
}
```

I want to get the month and year in which the water level is 0 feet which is being printed in the last line without using the loops. I dont know how to implement the above program without using loops. If any one can help, it would be great.
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: are you shure you can not use any loop? Or may be you can not use just 'while' or 'for'.
and no recursive functions either?

Comment: @AlexanderSobetskiy Yes it is an assignment from my university and they have restricted us not to use loops and functions. As we have only done switch and if else in university till now

Comment: can you tell me the water level is given in the beginning of the month or at the end?

Comment: at the end of the month

Answer (score 1):

test this and change code if my logic is wrong

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int m, y, lev;
    cout << "Enter current month number: ";
    cin >> m;
     cout << "Enter current year: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter current water level: ";
    cin >> lev;
   
    int avg_year    = 300;                  // average year decrease 
    int year_count  = lev/avg_year;         // how many entire years we will be decreasing for sure  
    lev = lev % avg_year;                   // how much level we still have after entire years have pass
    
    if ((lev > 0) &&  (m <= 8) && (m >=2))        // march - aug we are adding +150 each month 
    {
        int delta = (6 - m + 2);            // how much times we should add +150
        lev = lev + 150*delta;
        m = m + delta;
    }
    
    if((lev > 0) && (m  == 8))             // end of aug (sep = -200)
    {
        m++;
        lev = lev - 200;
    }
    if((lev > 0) && (m  == 9))             // end of sep (oct = -200)
    {
        m++;
        lev = lev - 200;
    }
    if((lev > 0) && (m  == 10))             // end of oct (nov = -200)
    {
        m++;
        lev = lev - 200;
    }
    if((lev > 0) && (m  == 11))             // end of nov (dec = -200)
    {
        m++;
        lev = lev - 200;
    }
    if((lev > 0) && (m == 12))             // end of dec (jan = -200)
    {
        m = 1;
        year_count++;
        lev = lev - 200;
    }
    
   
    /*
        in case at the beginning of the program m== 1 AND Level == (801 - 899)
        2 years past and we are at m == 1 with level == (201 - 299)
        februarry gives -200. So at the end of m==2, level == (1 - 99)
        
        when we do march-december we gain +100 level
        
        so in the beginning of the next year jan level will be 101-199
        and since jan takes -200 from level. It is definitely next years jan
        so we are just increasing year count
    */
    if((lev > 0) && (m  == 1))             // enf of jan (feb = -200)
    {
       lev = lev - 200;
       if(lev <= 0)
            m++;
        else
            year_count++;
    }
       

   cout << (y + year_count)  << "\t" << m << endl;
}
```

UPD
this is bellow I think the right solution as I would do it with all the loops. I doubt it can be achieved just by plain code with no loops or recursion

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int level_func(int m, int y, int lev)
{
    int ar[] = { -200, -200, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, -200, -200, -200, -200 };    

    int m_count = 0;
    while (lev > 0)
    {
        m++;
        m_count++;
        if (m > 12)
            m = 1;
        lev = lev + ar[m - 1];
    } 
    return m_count;
}

int main() {
    int m, y, lev;
    cout << "Enter current month number: ";
    cin >> m;
    cout << "Enter current year: ";
    cin >> y;
    cout << "Enter current water level: ";
    cin >> lev;

    int month_count = level_func(m, y, lev);
    y = y + month_count / 12;
    m = m + month_count % 12;

    if (m > 12)
    {
        y++;
        m = m - 12;
    }  

    cout << y << "\t" << m << endl;
}
```

Comment: I will check it. I have created my own very simple logic. I will do some checks on it and then check yours . Thanks for working on it. I have upvoted you for your effort

Comment: There are minor errors for which I was testing my script. Like having in mind which month was from when the water level is being tested. I will give example: Current month is 5 and water level is 1750 then the total month would be 70. and years instead of 5 will be 6 and three months on next year

Comment: @farhanjatt I created excel sheet for testing your scenario (m==5, level==1750) and my program is wrong. But you are not right either. After 4 years when m==5, level==550. With average -300 each year I assumed that after another year when m==5, level == 250. But it is wrong. After 4 years when m==5, level==500 it takes only 8 month to get level to 0. So, I doubt that this problem can be right solved without loops and arrays involved

Comment: I will post my answer. I have not tested my script properly due to lack of time but I also think there might be errors which can be easily fixed. Thanks for giving such time.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the solution myself and found a very efficient way to do it. I calculated total months required and got the total years from the month.The code is below

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int exact_months,year = 0;
    int c_month, c_year, wlevel, avg_decrease;
    cout<<"Enter current month number: ";
    cin>>c_month;
    cout<<"Enter current water level: ";
    cin>>wlevel;
    cout<<"Enter current year: ";
    cin>>c_year;
    int mn; 
    exact_months = wlevel/25;
    mn = (c_month+exact_months)%12;
    if ((c_month+exact_months)%12 !=0 && c_month != 1)
        year = 1;
    year = exact_months/12+year;
    cout<<"Date: "<<year+c_year<<":"<<mn;
}
```